# Does SSH on Mac keep a local cache of data?

Tags: backup, ssh

If I'm say, editing a file in VIM, the state of the remote machine needs to be sent to my Mac. I know that browsers cache images and such. Does SSH do the same? Are there any programs for Mac that do that? Would I be able to use that data to recover remote files?

Comment: Define "data" in this context.  HTTP clients (browsers) cache specific objects based on server and client caching and privacy policies.  SSH is a completely different paradigm...what data would you be interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH simply allows you to use a shell (command line) on a remote machine; it doesn't cache the data that you access.

If you're looking for a solution to back up files from another machine, and Time Machine isn't what you want, perhaps check out [rsync](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/).

Comment: Looks like rsync is the answer.